# Play2 Framework/Scala: Action composition

Tags: scala, playframework, action, composition

The documentation of the Play2 Framework suggests to build a new action like this:

```
class UserRequest[A](val user: Option[User], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object AuthAction extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (UserRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    val user = User(some data...)
    block(new UserRequest(Some(user),request))
  }
}
```

Now I found a blog that does it completely different. Please see here:
http://bryangilbert.com/code/2013/07/05/action-composition-auth/

Have a look at the block.

```
def FacebookAuthenticated(f: FacebookAuthenticatedRequest => Result) = {
    Action { request => .....
```

Instead of using ActionBuilder an independent function is defined that just uses Action inside. For me the Action composition in the blog looks much more convenient. Further more it enables to pass parameters to the new function.

Now my question is: Is there any advantage of extending ActionBuilder instead of using the technique in the blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cover the possibility to have async actions (`Request => Future[Result]`) and then to accept different body parsers (`BodyParser[T] => Request[T] => Future[Result]`) you will probably end up with something about as complicated as `ActionBuilder`.

You will probably also end up with a syntax for covering all those cases that is exactly like the action builder or very different which might confuse other developers, but that's probably not a big problem.

If your needs are as simple, always the same, either `Result` or `Future[Result]` with no body parsers then it probably is a good fit for you. If you further down the road find some problems then it will probably not be a lot of work to change into using `ActionBuilder`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to pass **def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (UserRequest[A]) => Future[Result])** additional parameters. And that's something I like to do.

Comment: One way would be to create a class instead of an object that extends ActionBuilder and let that class take parameters to its constructor, another would be to create a method that takes parameters and let that method create an ActionBuilder instance, which would have access to the parameters.